# Forbidden request when login in using Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

When I am logging in manually to `http://www.littlewoods.com/`, it works and displays error message.

When it is automated using selenium, it giving forbidden error.

Code:

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.navigate().to("url");
textBoxUserName.sendKeys(username);
Thread.sleep(5000);
textBoxPassword.sendKeys(Password);
Thread.sleep(5000);
textBoxPostCode.sendKeys(PostalCode);
Thread.sleep(5000);
//Robot rb=new Robot();
//rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
buttonLogin.click();
```

Comment: Instead of robot function. Try with xpath to click whether you are getting the same error.

Comment: Don't put your credentials in a question.

Comment: I have checked it with firefox and it successfully launches the url without any error as you mentioned. Are you getting this forbidden while launching the site?

Comment: Maybe Your user-agent for FirefoxDriver is forbidden at "http://www.littlewoods.com" by robots.txt file or by software.

Comment: @santhosh kumar - Try giving credentials(un: archanadbreddy@gmail.com , Pwd: archana123 , postcode :l13ed) and click on sign in...i am getting forbidden request at that time. Tried it by clearing cache also. This happens only during automation. Manually it is working fine.

Comment: @Guy - This is just for testing purpose, anyways it will not login.

Comment: Can you confirm the postcode please. Also, in the code you have pasted in the question, where we clicking the signin/register button after launching the site?

Comment: @santhosh kumar- postcode is L13ED,yes,after launching the site,try to login to that by using above credentials and click on sign in button,u get forbidden message

Comment: Site is not available now

Comment: Can you please try it after sometime